# How to find out why my app "stopped working"?

Tags: .net, windows-7

My app works for me on my machine. But another user (who can use it on his machine too) says it doesn't work for him on a server machine. But the server just says "Program Name has stopped working." There's a "View Problem Details" command but it doesn't tell me enough:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:                        CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01:                       programname.exe
  Problem Signature 02:                       0.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03:                       4e20a786
  Problem Signature 04:                       mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05:                       2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06:                       4d8c1599
  Problem Signature 07:                       f9b
  Problem Signature 08:                       80
  Problem Signature 09:                       System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  OS Version:                                          6.1.7600.2.0.0.16.7
  Locale ID:                                             1033
```

The very first lines of `Main()` install an "unhandled exception handler" which is supposed to show a window with a stack trace. It worked fine until now.

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.Automatic);
Application.ThreadException += ShowUnhandledException;
```

Is there any way I can get a call stack? P.S. I need it in the next hour ;)

Comment: loading external files and not checking for errors?

Comment: The System.IO.FileNotFoundExcdeption would indicate that SOMETHING's been looked for... maybe an external .dll that's being implicitly loaded and isn't installed on the friend's machine.

Comment: Looks like a problem loading the assembly.  How is this app being deployed?  What kind of app is it?  What framework are you targeting?

Comment: Maybe you could create a simple wrapper app that tries to use reflection to load this assembly and wraps the whole attempt in a try..catch block.  Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx#Y1275

Comment: Reflection to load what assembly? You mean the .exe file? Hmm, if I could get access to the server, I guess I could do something like that. Or even have the user try it.

Comment: Yeah, the CLR will only load an assembly when it's needed (JIT), thus, since you are only referencing this troublesome assembly via a String, it won't crash right away, unless your new app crashes too.  Output the exception to a file or send it to yourself in an email or write it to a db table.  If you don't have access to the environment in even an indirect way I don't know how you are going to solve this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my installer program (MSI) got broken at some point, and did not include 2 of 7 DLLs used by my program.

It is still not clear why the ThreadException handler didn't work (.NET should have called Main() even though DLLs were missing, since .NET loads dependencies on-demand, and AFAIK only the UI thread was running; but as it's fixed it's not pressing to investigate further.)

Answer (score 3):

> Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.Automatic);

That only catches and displays exceptions that occur due to event handlers that run on the UI thread.  It is no substitute for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, the event that runs when code crashes on a worker thread.

But the trace you posted gives some odds for another problem: your code might be crashing before it even got started.  System.IO.FileNotFoundException is an exception that's raised when you didn't make sure that the proper version of .NET was installed on the client machine.  Easy to take care of with a Setup and Deployment project.  Or asking your friend to enable Windows Update.

Comment: The lack of the correct framework would also have been my suggestion and is usually the cause when an app crashes instantly without even showing some UI.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project.  Add a reference to your real project.  In your application you can use the Assembly.Load("..") method to load the other project and this can be done in a try..catch block.  Since the CLR does JIT compiling, your new app should start (unless whatever is going wrong is not specific to the particular app in question, but rather something to do with your default project setup) and after it has started it should be able to capture the stack trace of whatever is causing the other one to fail.  Capture this in some way (file, email, db) and have that other user get you this output.

At least that is my theory.  I don't have any programs that won't start to test this out on.  At least not in the time frame you've given.

PS==> If your wrapper app won't start, try creating a simple "Hello world" console app and see if that will even start.  Try targeting different .NET frameworks.  Create several of these little apps to test out different settings.  Perhaps you are targeting a 64 bit platform and the server is 32 bit?

Edit:  Not sure how to make this work because when you add a project reference to an assembly that is executable, it doesn't create a .exe file with the build for the second assembly, it seems.  So looks like you just need to load the executable from the file system from the other install...